# How should I loop this program?

Tags: java, loops

Basically I need to loop this. I created a game where you answer questions about fish in runescape and I would like it to loop like say would ‘you go again’ or something. How would I go about this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GameDriver
{
  public static void main(String a[])
{
  Game g = new Game();
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  String buf = null;

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     System.out.print(g.askQuestion());
     buf = s.nextLine();

     if(g.confirm(buf))
        System.out.println("You're Right!");
     else
        System.out.println("You're Wrong...");
  }

  System.out.println("You got a " + g.getScore());
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFB complete code for ‘you go again’ program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameDriver {

    public static void Gamer(Scanner s) {

        Game g = new Game();

        String buf = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.print(g.askQuestion());
            buf = s.nextLine();

            if (g.confirm(buf))
                System.out.println("You're Right!");
            else
                System.out.println("You're Wrong...");
        }

        System.out.println("You got a " + g.getScore());

    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Press Enter to continue; Type Exit to quit");

                if (s.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                    s.close();
                    break;
                }

                Gamer(s);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @jake-wilks Run this as is and let us know result.

Comment: @jake-wilks Could you please vote/mark as solution? [Accept answer] stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer; [Vote] stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 2):

You could do while (true) loop and then if the user enters quit just break the loop like so:

```
if (buf.equals("quit"))
   break;
```

Comment: You replace the for loop by the while loop and then before doing g.confirm you verify if the user entered "quit"

Comment: sure, am i missing something?

Comment: I don't believe so honestly really new to this and need help i have three different codes this is just the game driver

Answer (score 0):

As per i understand your question,you want to loop over the for loop.Kindly correct me if i m wrong.

```
char c='y';//'y' means user wants to go again
while(c=='y')// to check the user reply.
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
         System.out.print(g.askQuestion());
         buf = s.nextLine();

         if(g.confirm(buf))
           System.out.println("You're Right!");
         else
           System.out.println("You're Wrong...");
      }

      System.out.println("You got a " + g.getScore());
      System.out.println("Do you wanna go again?");
      c=s.next.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is shortest solution keeping all your code logic as is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameDriver {

    public static void Gamer(Scanner s) {

        Game g = new Game();

        String buf = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.print(g.askQuestion());
            buf = s.nextLine();

            if (g.confirm(buf))
                System.out.println("You're Right!");
            else
                System.out.println("You're Wrong...");
        }

        System.out.println("You got a " + g.getScore());

        System.out.print("Press Enter to continue; Type Exit to quit");

        if (s.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            s.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Gamer(s);
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        Gamer(new Scanner(System.in));
    }
}
```

Comment: @jake-wilks Run this code as is and let us know result.

Comment: I used this thank you, now I have to add inheritance to my overall program could you help me with that by chance?